# How to select a enabled date from a calendar in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, calendar

I want to select a date from a calendar using selenium web driver and c# .Already booked dates are disabled in the calendar and i want to find a enabled date and click it.Disabled dates are in yellow color and enabled dates are in blue color and there is a common xpath for all the enabled dates.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

first, get all elements of enabled dates by using "XPath" and store it in a "List" as shown below. "use your "XPath" "

List elements=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='products/']"));

now you get all enabled dates, among those elements, get the first element as given below.

WebElement Elem = (WebElement)elements.get(0);

Then click on that element.

Elem.click();